# Block numeric in EditText android using input filter

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I want to do it programmatically by input filter not in xml like e.g - android:digits="aA".

Here is my code

```
public static void RemoveCharacter(EditText text, String character, int length) {
final String blockCharacterSet = character;
// final String blockCharacterSet = "\"+[]&~#^|$%*!@/()-'\\\":;,?{}=!$^';,?×÷<>{}€£¥₩%~`¤♡♥_|《》¡¿°•○●□■◇◆♧♣▲▼▶◀↑↓←→☆★▪:-);-):-D:-(:'(:O\";
InputFilter[] filter1 = new InputFilter[2];
filter1[0] = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
filter1[1] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length);


text.setFilters(filter1);

}
```

It is completely working in Moto G,nexus devices but not working in Samsung devices.

Comment: Please note that asking volunteers for urgency is usually a reliable downvote attractor - remember that it is only urgent for you, and readers will answer questions at their leisure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really want to do it with `InputFilter` it will be a little bit more complex than that.

Different keyboards act really differently, so i my guess is your solution won't be working with Swype/Swift keyboards.

Probably try using something like this:

```
    final Set<Character> blockSet = new HashSet<>();
    blockSet.addAll(Arrays.asList('1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'));

    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                    char[] v = new char[end - start];
                    TextUtils.getChars(source, start, end, v, 0);
                    String s = new String(v);

                    if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                        CharSequence sp = new SpannableString(s);
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source,
                                start, end, null, (Spannable) sp, 0);

                        boolean containsDigit = true;
                        while (containsDigit) {
                            containsDigit = false;
                            for (int j = 0; j < sp.length(); j++) {
                                if (blockSet.contains(sp.charAt(j))) {
                                    sp = TextUtils.concat(sp.subSequence(0, j), sp.subSequence(j + 1, sp.length()));
                                    containsDigit = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        return sp;
                    } else {
                        s = s.replaceAll("\\d", "");
                        return s;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null; // keep original
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your choice of input type using below code, it will work:

```
your_editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Thanks Yaar Kaushik but its still not working for samsung devices..:(